# openpyxl problem Keyerror Content_Types.xml

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I have a problem reading the code with openpyxl, until yesterday it works, and now it doesn't work anymore, I tried also with a backup copy but I have the same problem, I deleted the excel files...
I also tried on another computer and I have the same error.
this is the code:

```
# Writing on a EXCEL FILE
filename = (f"{myPath}/Monatsplan {userfinder} {month} {year}.xlsx")
dienstorinfo = string1
emptycell = ' '   
x = len(dienstorinfo)
if x == 0:
    dienstorinfo = tagesinfo2
try:
    wb = load_workbook(filename)
    ws = wb.worksheets[0]  # select first worksheet
except FileNotFoundError:
    headers_row = ['Datum','Dienst','Funktion','Von','Bis','Schichtdauer','Bezahlte Zeit','Überzeit','Sonnats Zulage','Nachtdienst']
    wb = Workbook()
    ws = wb.active
wb.save(filename)
ws.append([soup_datum,dienstorinfo,soup_funktion,(soup_dienstbegin),(soup_dienstende),(soup_schichtdauer),(soup_bezahltezeit),emptycell,emptycell])

for cols in ws.iter_cols(  ):
     if cols[-1].value:
        cols[-1].border = Border(left=Side(style='thin'),right=Side(style='thin'),top=Side(style='thin'),bottom=Side(style='thin'))                                
ws.column_dimensions['A'].width = 11
ws.row_dimensions['1'].height = 25
ws.column_dimensions['B'].width = 60   
ws.column_dimensions['C'].width = 2   
ws.column_dimensions['D'].width = 3   
ws.column_dimensions['E'].width = 3   
ws.column_dimensions['F'].width = 3   
ws.column_dimensions['H'].width = 3        
ws.column_dimensions['I'].width = 2   
ws.column_dimensions['L'].width = 2   
wb.save(filename)              
wb.close()
```

a this is the response:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Diriye\OneDrive\Python\tuxapp\Monatseint_Tool_v1.1.py", line 408, in <module>
    scraping()
  File "c:\Users\Diriye\OneDrive\Python\tuxapp\Monatseint_Tool_v1.1.py", line 364, in scraping
    excel()

    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Diriye\OneDrive\Python\tuxapp\Monatseint_Tool_v1.1.py", line 408, in <module>
    scraping()
  File "c:\Users\Diriye\OneDrive\Python\tuxapp\Monatseint_Tool_v1.1.py", line 364, in scraping
    excel()
  File "c:\Users\Diriye\OneDrive\Python\tuxapp\Monatseint_Tool_v1.1.py", line 340, in excel
    wb = load_workbook(filename)
  File "C:\Users\Diriye\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 317, in load_workbook
    reader.read()
  File "C:\Users\Diriye\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 276, in read
    self.read_manifest()
  File "C:\Users\Diriye\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 134, in read_manifest
    src = self.archive.read(ARC_CONTENT_TYPES)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\zipfile.py", line 1463, in read
    with self.open(name, "r", pwd) as fp:
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\zipfile.py", line 1502, in open
    zinfo = self.getinfo(name)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\zipfile.py", line 1429, in getinfo
    raise KeyError(
KeyError: "There is no item named '[Content_Types].xml' in the archive"
```

Comment: Whatever file you've downloaded isn't valid.

Answer (score 0):

The issue for me that i created and .ods file type, and rename it to .xlsx file. if this is the case for you or others
To solve the issue you need to convert the .ods to .xlsx, I used online converter and it worker for me.
https://www.zamzar.com/convert/ods-to-xls/

make sure to specify .xlsx as file type

Answer (score 0):

in my case this mistake was because of this code:

```
sheet.row_dimensions[row_in_excel_file].hidden = False

row_in_excel_file had type "str", but should be 'int'
```

this code solve problem:

```
sheet.row_dimensions[int(row_in_excel_file)].hidden = False
```